$AB=0$ implies $BA=0 $, describe $A$
Can you help me with this exercise, please?

Consider a matrix $A$ in the space of $n \times n$ real matrices, denoted by $\cal M_n(\Bbb R)$. Given the condition: For all matrices $B \in \cal M_n(\Bbb R)$, if $AB=0$ then $BA=0$.
Describe the matrix $A$.

What I have found so far:
First, I have observed that if $k \in \cal \Bbb R$, then $A=kI_n$ (where $I_n$ is the identity matrix) satisfies this condition because such matrices commute with every matrix. More generally, if $A$ is invertible,it satisfies the conditions because $AB=0$ implies $B=0$ implies $BA=0$

What have you tried? Can you write down examples of matrices that satisfy this condition? Can you write down examples that don't?

I have noticed the matrix A = lambda*In satisfy this condition because it commutes with any matrix. There are many examples that don't satisfy the condition
for ex  :
A= 0 1
0 0
in M2(R)

when do two matrices commute?

two matrices A and B commute when AB=BA

You already know that the given condition is satisfied by all invertible matrices. What about singular matrices?

@DietrichBurde They already addressed that exact example in a comment above.

@Arthur Now I see it. Without MathJax it is hard to see it.

If I need to show that the result is false for non-invertible and non-zero matrices,
I need to find a matrix $B$ such that $AB=0$ but $BA \neq 0$.
If I take a non-zero vector $X$ in $\ker(A)$ and a non-zero vector $Y$ in $\text{Im}(A)$,
I thought that by considering $XY^T$ we might achieve something.

You have seen that any invertible $A$ fulfils this, as does the zero matrix.
So what if $A$ is neither of these?  In that case $A$ has both non-zero image / range and non-zero kernel / null space. Now we construct a $B$ such that $0=AB\neq BA$:
Take a non-zero $v\in \ker A$ and a non-zero $w\in \operatorname{img}A$. Consider $B=vw^T$. The range of $B$ is $\operatorname{Span}v$, so $ABx$ is zero for any vector $x$, and therefore $AB=0$. On the other hand, there is a vector $y$ such that $Ay=w$. This yields $$BAy=Bw=vw^Tw=\|w\|^2v\neq0$$proving that $BA\neq0$.

thank you ! so the answer is A invertible.

@mathsmaths Or zero.

The matrices can be with entries in any field $k$, not necessarily $\Bbb R$.
The condition $AB=0\implies BA=0$ is equivalent to: for any subspaces $U,V\subseteq k^n$ such that $\dim U+\dim V=n$,$U\subseteq \ker A\implies \operatorname{im}A\subseteq V$, which in turn is equivalent to the same property restricted to $U=\ker A$, i.e. to: $\operatorname{im}A$ is equal to every subspace $V\subseteq k^n$ having the same dimension as $\operatorname{im}A$. This happens iff this dimension is $0$ or $n$, i.e. iff $A=0$ or $A$ is invertible.
